# Do I need to charge VAT to other VAT registered businesses?

Tags: united-kingdom, accounting, vat

If I invoice a client who is VAT registered, and I am VAT registered, do I need to add on VAT even though they will claim this back from HMRC?

I'm sure I've seen online somewhere where adding in a VAT registration number removed the VAT from the total I had to pay, but I could be talking nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely.

You are either VAT registered or you are not. If you are not VAT registered then you don't charge anyone VAT. If you are VAT registered, then you charge everyone VAT, without exception. (Well, if you deal with customers abroad, then you ask a qualified tax advisor instead of me).

Of course there is a rule that above a certain revenue in a year you MUST register for VAT.